# awk script to sum numbers in a column over a loop not working for some iterations in the loop

Tags: awk

#### Sample input

```
12.0000 0.6000000 0.05
13.0000 1.6000000 0.05
14.0000 2.6000000 0.05
15.0000 3.0000000 0.05
15.0000 3.2000000 0.05
15.0000 3.4000000 0.05
15.0000 3.6000000 0.10
15.0000 3.8000000 0.10
15.0000 4.0000000 0.10
15.0000 4.2000000 0.11
15.0000 4.4000000 0.12
15.0000 4.6000000 0.13
15.0000 4.8000000 0.14
15.0000 5.0000000 0.15
15.0000 5.2000000 0.14
15.0000 5.4000000 0.13
15.0000 5.6000000 0.12
15.0000 5.8000000 0.11
15.0000 6.0000000 0.10
15.0000 6.2000000 0.10
15.0000 6.4000000 0.10
15.0000 6.6000000 0.05
15.0000 6.8000000 0.05
15.0000 7.0000000 0.05
```

#### Goal

1. Print line 1 in output as 0 0
2. For $2 = 5.000000, $3 = 0.15.

   - Print line 2 in output as 1 0.15
3. For $2 = 4.800000 through $2 = 5.200000, sum+=$3 for each line (i.e. 0.14 + 0.15 + 0.14 = 0.43).

   - Print line 3 in output as 2 0.43.
4. For $2 = 4.600000 through $2 = 5.400000, sum+=$3 for each line (i.e. 0.13 + 0.14 + 0.15 + 0.14 + 0.13 = 0.69).

   - Print line 4 in output as 3 0.69
5. Continue this pattern until $2 = 5.000000 +- 1.6 (9 lines total, plus line 1 as 0 0 = 10 total lines in output)

#### Desired Output

```
0 0
1 0.15
2 0.43
3 0.69
4 0.93
5 1.15
6 1.35
7 1.55
8 1.75
9 1.85
```

#### Attempt

Script 1

```
#!/bin/bash

for (( i=0; i<=8; i++ )); do

awk '$2 >= 5.0000000-'$i'*0.2 {sum+=$3}
     $2 == 5.0000000+'$i'*0.2 {print '$i', sum; exit
     }' test.dat
     done > test.out
```

produces

```
0 0.15
1 0.43
2 0.69
3 0.93
4 1.15
5 1.35
6 1.55
7 1.75
8 1.85
```

This is very close. However, the output is missing 0 0 for line 1, and because of this, lines 2 through 10 have $1 and $2 mismatched by 1 line.

Script 2

```
#!/bin/bash

for (( i=0; i<=8; i++ )); do

awk ''$i'==0 {sum=0}
     '$i'>0 && $2 > 5.0000000-'$i'*0.2 {sum+=$3}
     $2 == 5.0000000+'$i'*0.2 - ('$i' ? 0.2 : 0) {print '$i', sum; exit
     }' test.dat
     done > test.out
```

which produces

```
0 0
1 0.15
2 0.43
4 0.93
5 1.15
6 1.35
7 1.55
```

$1 and $2 are now correctly matched. However, I am missing the lines with $1=3, $1=8, and $1=9 completely. Adding the ternary operator causes my code to skip these iterations in the loop somehow.

#### Question

Can anyone explain what's wrong with script 2, or how to achieve the desired output in one line of code? Thank you.

#### Solution

I used Ed Morton's solution to solve this. Both of them work for different goals. Instead of using the modulus to save array space, I constrained the array to $1 = 15.0000. I did this instead of the modulus in order to include two other "key" variables that I had wanted to also sum over at different parts of the input, into separate output files.

Furthermore, as far as I understood it, the script summed only for lines with $2 >= 5.0000000, and then multiplied the summation by 2, in order to include the lines with $2 <= 5.0000000. This works for the sample input here because I made $3 symmetric around 0.15. I modified it to sum them separately, though.

```
awk 'BEGIN { key=5; range=9}
$1 == 15.0000 {     
      a[NR] = $3
}
$2 == key { keyIdx = NR}
END {
    print (0, 0) > "test.out"
    sum = a[keyIdx]
    for (delta=1; delta<=range; delta++) {
        print (delta, sum) > "test.out"
        plusIdx = (keyIdx + delta) 
        minusIdx = (keyIdx - delta)
        sum += a[plusIdx] + a[minusIdx]
    }
    exit
}' test.dat
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195385/discussion-on-question-by-blaisem-awk-script-to-sum-numbers-in-a-column-over-a-l).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
$ cat tst.awk
$2 == 5 { keyNr = NR }
{ nr2val[NR] = $3 }
END {
    print 0, 0
    sum = nr2val[keyNr]
    for (delta=1; delta<=9; delta++) {
        print delta, sum
        sum += nr2val[keyNr+delta] + nr2val[keyNr-delta]
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
0 0
1 0.15
2 0.43
3 0.69
4 0.93
5 1.15
6 1.35
7 1.55
8 1.75
9 1.85
```

We could optimize it to only store `2*(range=9)` values in `vals[]` (using a modulus operator `NR%(2*range)` for the index) and do the calculation when we hit an `NR` that's `range` lines past the line where `$2 == key` rather than doing it after we've read the whole of the input if it's either too slow or your input file is too big to store all in memory, e.g.:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { key=5; range=9 }
{
    idx = NR % (2*range)
    nr2val[idx] = $3
}
$2 == key { keyIdx = idx; endNr = NR+range }
NR == endNr { exit }
END {
    print 0, 0
    sum = nr2val[keyIdx]
    for (delta=1; delta<=range; delta++) {
        print delta, sum
        idx = (keyIdx + delta) % (2*range)
        sum += nr2val[idx] + nr2val[idx]
    }
    exit
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
0 0
1 0.15
2 0.43
3 0.69
4 0.93
5 1.15
6 1.35
7 1.55
8 1.75
9 1.85
```

Comment: I was able to adapt this successfully. Thanks as always Ed. One question, just as a matter of curiosity: Do you happen to know why the script 2 resulted in that particular output, with the 3rd and 8th rows missing? I also got the same erroneous output when I did printf "0 0\n" > test.out followed by script 1, which was exactly copied from your previous answer in the comments. The scripts use a loop where each step of the loop generates one line in the output. If most steps in the loop successfully generate lines, I found it strange that it seemed to randomly fail for a few of the steps.

Comment: You're welcome. No, sorry, I can't quite wrap my brain around what that script is trying to do (without a lot more effort than I'm willing to put in) so idk how/why it's failing.

Comment: I will say though that the condition `$2 == 5.0000000+'$i'*0.2 - ('$i' ? 0.2 : 0)` is extremely complicated and reliant on order of precedence of operators so you might want to add some parentheses and/or simplify it with some variables for intermediate results. Does `$2 == 5.0000000+x*y` mean `($2 == 5.0000000)+(x*y)` or `$2 == ((5.0000000+x)*y)` or something else? I honestly don't know what that whole expression evaluates to. Also use `-v var=val` instead of letting `'$i'` be expanded by the shell befroe awk then interprets it - see http://cfajohnson.com/shell/cus-faq-2.html#Q24.

Comment: why is it better to introduce shell variables into awk like this? Is it slower if the shell has to expand the variable before awk interprets it?

Comment: No, the shell has to expand it either way but it's more robust in that it'll work for any value of the shell variable rather than just those shell variables that contain valid awk syntax+semantics for the context in which the variable is used and doesn't lead to cryptic error messages. To see one example of the differences try `x=$(printf 'foo\nbar'); awk -v x="$x" 'BEGIN{print x}'` and then try the "equivalent" of `x=$(printf 'foo\nbar'); awk 'BEGIN{print "'$x'"}'`. Note how the former works just fine and the latter fails with cryptic error messages.

Answer (score 0):

I like your problem. It is an adequate challenge.

My approach is to put all possible into the `awk` script. And scan the input file only once. Because I/O manipulation is slower than computation (these days).

Do as many computation (actually 9) on the relevant input line.

The required inputs are variable `F1` and text file `input.txt`

The execution command is:

```
awk -v F1=95 -f script.awk input.txt
```

So the logic is:

```
1. Initialize: Compute the 9 range markers and store their values in an array.

2. Store the 3rd input value in an order array `field3`. We use this array to compute the sum.

3. On each line that has 1st field equals 15.0000. 

3.1 If found begin marker then mark it.

3.2 If found end marker then compute the sum, and mark it.

4. Finalize: Output all the computed results
```

`script.awk` including few debug printout to assist in debugging

```
BEGIN {
    itrtns = 8; # iterations count consistent all over the program.
    for (i = 0; i <= itrtns; i++) { # compute range markers per iteration
        F1start[i] = (F1 - 2 - i)/5 - 14; # print "F1start["i"]="F1start[i];
        F1stop[i] = (F1 - 2 + i)/5 - 14; # print  "F1stop["i"]="F1stop[i];
        b[i] = F1start[i] + (i ? 0.2 : 0); # print "b["i"]="b[i];
    }
}
{    field3[NR] = $3;}  # store 3rd input field in ordered array.
$1==15.0000 { # for each input line that has 1st input field 15.0000
    currVal = $2 + 0; # convert 2nd input field to numeric value
    for (i = 0; i <= itrtns; i++) { # on each line scan for range markers
        # print "i="i, "currVal="currVal, "b["i"]="b[i], "F1stop["i"]="F1stop[i], isZero(currVal-b[i]), isZero(currVal-F1stop[i]);
        if (isZero(currVal - b[i])) { # if there is a begin marker
            F1idx[i] = NR; # store the marker index postion
            # print "F1idx["i"] =", F1idx[i];
        }
        if (isZero(currVal - F1stop[i])) { # if there is an end marker
            for (s = F1idx[i]; s <= NR; s++) {sum[i] += field3[s];} # calculate its sum
            F2idx[i] = NR; # store its end marker postion (for debug report)
            # print "field3["NR"]=", field3[NR];
        }
    }
}
END { # output the computed results
    for (i = 0; i <= itrtns; i++) {print i, sum[i], "rows("F1idx[i]"-"F2idx[i]")"}
}
function isZero(floatArg) { # floating point number pecision comparison
    tolerance = 0.00000000001;
    if (floatArg < tolerance && floatArg > -1 * tolerance )
        return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Provided `input.txt` from the question.

```
12.0000 0.6000000 0.05
13.0000 1.6000000 0.05
14.0000 2.6000000 0.05
15.0000 3.0000000 0.05
15.0000 3.2000000 0.05
15.0000 3.4000000 0.05
15.0000 3.6000000 0.10
15.0000 3.8000000 0.10
15.0000 4.0000000 0.10
15.0000 4.2000000 0.11
15.0000 4.4000000 0.12
15.0000 4.6000000 0.13
15.0000 4.8000000 0.14
15.0000 5.0000000 0.15
15.0000 5.2000000 0.14
15.0000 5.4000000 0.13
15.0000 5.6000000 0.12
15.0000 5.8000000 0.11
15.0000 6.0000000 0.10
15.0000 6.2000000 0.10
15.0000 6.4000000 0.10
15.0000 6.6000000 0.05
15.0000 6.8000000 0.05
15.0000 7.0000000 0.05
```

The output for: `awk -v F1=95 -f script.awk  input.txt`

```
0 0.13 rows(12-12)
1 0.27 rows(12-13)
2 0.54 rows(11-14)
3 0.79 rows(10-15)
4 1.02 rows(9-16)
5 1.24 rows(8-17)
6 1.45 rows(7-18)
7 1.6 rows(6-19)
8 1.75 rows(5-20)
```

The output for: `awk -v F1=97 -f script.awk  input.txt`

```
0 0.15 rows(14-14)
1 0.29 rows(14-15)
2 0.56 rows(13-16)
3 0.81 rows(12-17)
4 1.04 rows(11-18)
5 1.25 rows(10-19)
6 1.45 rows(9-20)
7 1.65 rows(8-21)
8 1.8 rows(7-22)
```